# How to draw full with horizontal line

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I tried to create bootstrap 3 site with logo in left columns and row rows in right.

Row is right should be separated by full width horizontal line as show in picture.

I tried to use hr element to create horizontal ine using

```
<section class='row'>
   <div class='col-lg-3 col-lg-offset-1'>
      <img src='StoreImage/Media/pv-logo.png' />
   </div>
   <div class='row'>
      <div class='col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-2'>
         <span>EST</span>
         <span>&nbsp;|&nbsp;</span>
         <span>ENG</span>
      </div>
      <div class='col-lg-offset-1 col-lg-2'>
         <span>SISENE</span>
         <span>&nbsp;|&nbsp;</span>
         <span>OSTUKORV</span>
      </div>
      <br>
      <hr style='border-top: 2px solid #b49258'>
      <div class='col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-4'>
         <span>MEIST </span>
         <span>&nbsp;|&nbsp;</span>
         <span>ILUBLOGI</span>
         <span>&nbsp;|&nbsp;</span>
         <img class="frame-21" src="StoreImage/Media/otsi.png"/>
         <span>  </span>
         <input placeholder='Otsi'/>
      </div>
   </div>
   </div>
</section>
```

but there is some white space before horizontal line starts.

Also hr element is placed outside of bootstrap 3 column div. Not sure is this proper way to use bootstrap 3

How to create this layout properly ?
Bootstrap 3 is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   <div class='col-lg-3 col-lg-offset-1'>
      <img src='StoreImage/Media/pv-logo.png' />
   </div>
```

The above-mentioned div is overlapping your `<hr>`.

You can change the div's class from `col-lg-3` to `col-lg-2` to make ur `<hr>` look more extended.